# Question about accessing object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, getter, object-literal

I just started learning javascript using codecademy and I'm doing a quiz on object properties.

One of the questions is as follows:

**"Which of the following lines of code would print the value saved to the _num key in the tempObj object?"**

The code is:

```
let tempObj = {
    _num: 22,
    get num() {
       return this._num;
  }
};
```

One of the correct answers was `console.log(tempObj['num']);`

However, I'm confused by this because wouldn't adding the quotation marks around 'num' make the computer evaluate it as a string rather than as a getter? If not, why not?

Comment: *"wouldn't adding the quotation marks around 'num' make the computer evaluate it as a string"* - Indeed it does.  And it uses that string to access a property on the object using "bracket notation".  So `tempObj.num` is essentially the same as `tempObj['num']`.

Comment: To follow-up on what David said and complete the answer, the getter is used either way, whether `tempObj.num` or `tempObj['num']`. `tempObj[num]` would not be valid in this context.